# I am trying to get Users' Ip address and store it in vuex, then i will send it to backed in every request to product Detail

Tags: javascript, vuex

created state to store the ipaddress
**auth.js**

```
const state = {ipAddress: ''}

const getters = {ipAddress: (state) => {
    return state.ipAddress
     }
}
const actions = {
async getIpAddress ({commit}) {
    const { data: { ip } } = await axios.get("https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace", {responseType: "text", transformResponse: data =>
        Object.fromEntries(data.trim().split("\n").map(line => line.split("=")))
    });
    commit('setIp', ip)},
}
```

here is the `ip` address

```
const mutations = {
setIp(state, payload) {
    state.ipAddress = payload
},}
```

**App.vue**
Calling the fucntion ...

```
<script>
import { mapActions, mapState, mapGetters } from "vuex";
Vue.mixin(windowMixin)
export default {
    name: "App",

  methods: {
        ...mapActions('auth',['getIpAddress']),
},
  mounted() {
        this.getIpAddress();
    },
 };
</script>
```

product.service.js
sending the ip as a parameters

```
import ApiService from "../api.service";
const ProductService = {
  async productDetails(productID,ipAddress){
  const requestData = {
    method: 'get',
    url: `/api/products/v1/product/detail/?itemId=${productID}`,
    params: {
      detailToken: localStorage.getItem('detailData') && localStorage.getItem('detailData'),
      ip: ipAddress
   }
  }
```

Here I added this `ipAddress` to `productDetails` in another Component,
but I want to import it in `product.service.js` directly, Please help me !

Comment: Import `store` in your `product.service.js` and use whatever you need from that.

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov Could you please write how to do that in an answer field?

Comment: Do you have `store.js` file?

Comment: @Daniyal Of course Not , I am a new developer in this Project,

Comment: Then where do you set your Vuex store?

Comment: all data is stored in auth.js

Comment: Well, it's not so obvious how you set up the Vuex store. Anyway you should import your data from the file you set them up to your `product.service.js` and use there.